# If $p$ is prime then $(p-1)! \equiv p-1\pmod{\frac{p(p-1)}{2}} $

Tags: number-theory, modules, congruences

I need to prove this.

If $p$ prime then $(p-1)! \equiv p-1\pmod{\frac{p(p-1)}{2}} $.

I can use Lagrange's Theoremm, Wilson's Theorem and Fermat theorem.
Thank you.

Comment: just check that the congruence is true modulo $p$ (Wilson) and also modulo $(p-1)/2$ (both sides are congruent to $0$) (and check it separately for $p=2$, when $(p-1)/2$ is not an integer and so what I wrote fails)

Answer (score 1):

If $p=2$ then $p(p-1)/2=1$ divides everything. (Trivial case).

If $p$ is odd and $p\geq 3$ then $(p-1)!-(p-1)$ is obviously divisible by $(p-1)/2.$

If $p$ is an odd prime then $(p-1)!-(p-1)$ is divisible by $p$ (Wilson's Theorem). Since $(p-1)!-(p-1)$ is also divisible by $(p-1)/2$, and $\gcd (p,(p-1)/2)=1,$  it must be divisible by $p((p-1)/2).$

(If $a|c$ and $b|c$ and $\gcd (a,b)=1$ then $ab|c.$)

Comment: Why  $(p−1)/2$ divides to $(p-1)!-(p-1)$?

Comment: If  $p\geq 3$ and $p$ is odd then $[(p-1)!-(p-1)]/[(p-1)/2]=$ $[(p-2)!(p-1)-(p-1)]/[(p-1)/2]=$ $ (p-2)!\cdot 2-2.$ .. I should have said "If $ p$ is odd and $p\geq 3$...."